# Why do I have negative "Active DbContexts"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm using the [new event counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#event-counters) in EF Core 5.0. It currently lists `-2` `Active DbContexts`.

How can this possibly be negative? What does a negative count here indicate?

```
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore]
    Active DbContexts                                              -2
    Execution Strategy Operation Failures (Count / 1 sec)           0
    Execution Strategy Operation Failures (Total)                   0
    Optimistic Concurrency Failures (Count / 1 sec)                 0
    Optimistic Concurrency Failures (Total)                         0
    Queries (Count / 1 sec)                                         0
    Queries (Total)                                                38
    Query Cache Hit Rate (%)                                      NaN
    SaveChanges (Count / 1 sec)                                     0
    SaveChanges (Total)                                             0
```

This is after identifying and fixing a DbContext leak, where the number reported was in the thousands. I do see the number tick up (to `-1`) when a context is created, then back down to `-2` when the context is destroyed.

Comment: I would [create an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues)

Comment: Which exact version of EF Core are you using? This was fixed in 5.0.3 (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23630)

Comment: @ShayRojansky Ah... I'd found and looked at that exact issue but skimmed right over the line mentioning DbContext increment/decrement. I was on 5.0.2; that'd do it. Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug was fixed in EF Core 5.0.3 (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23630)